# Scale cassandra Streaming error (Null Pointer Exception)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, cassandra

We have a cluster with single node which has around 40GB data. We are trying to scale and add a second node to the cluster but unable to so. 
The seed node starts streaming the data but an error is thrown after some time. 
The error is :

```
ERROR [STREAM-OUT-/10.0.0.166] 2016-06-21 12:18:40,300 StreamSession.java:520 - [Stream #862ed0e0-37a7-11e6-b0b9-3fa2170fe9a5] Streaming error occurred
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.SerializationHeader$Component.access$500(SerializationHeader.java:283) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.jar:3.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.SerializationHeader$Serializer.serialize(SerializationHeader.java:430) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.jar:3.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.FileMessageHeader$FileMessageHeaderSerializer.serialize(FileMessageHeader.java:208) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.jar:3.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.OutgoingFileMessage.serialize(OutgoingFileMessage.java:84) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.jar:3.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.OutgoingFileMessage$1.serialize(OutgoingFileMessage.java:48) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.jar:3.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.OutgoingFileMessage$1.serialize(OutgoingFileMessage.java:40) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.jar:3.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.StreamMessage.serialize(StreamMessage.java:48) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.jar:3.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$OutgoingMessageHandler.sendMessage(ConnectionHandler.java:363) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.jar:3.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$OutgoingMessageHandler.run(ConnectionHandler.java:335) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.jar:3.3]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_72-internal]
```

When I do a nodetool bootstrap resume it again starts streaming data but after some throw same error.

Is there any bug in cassandra 3.3 or what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: I have faced the same issue and we can solve these issue by referring these link. [https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10961][1]

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to this [ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11065):

Have you checked this, maybe possible solution?

1. Get your schema: DESC SCHEMA;
2. Go with cqlsh on the new node.
3. Import the schema.
4. Add the new node to the cluster.

Or you can update to Cassandra 3.4

//Edit
sanjeev fixed it. SSTable wasn't in the Cassandra Version.

```
nodetool upgradesstables
```

solved this problem.

Comment: The ticket you mentioned is for a different exception, not the one I am getting.

Comment: Yes, i know but have you checked it?

Comment: Both are completely different exception. Also some data is transferred between the nodes, before it throws the exception.

Comment: Ahh, okay. Do you have empty fields in your tables? Maybe the transfer will stopped because there is an empty field in a row. Have you checked, maybe on a new clean development node, to overwrite it with empty strings? I know it's not really nice but when it helps it's a acceptable workaround.

Comment: I am not sure about that but there should be mechanism where it ignore empty row/column data.

Comment: That's totally true. But maybe this is the bug. If this will work you know that there isn't a mechanism for it. With this workaround you can add a new node and you can create a bug ticket in the Cassandra Jira. It's better than a failing node.

Comment: I actually did not get your work around mechanism. Can you be a little more clear what you are trying to say and how can I achieve that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115940/discussion-between-philipp-blum-and-sanjeev).

Answer (score 0):

Got a similar issue.

According to my logs :

```
cat /var/log/cassandra/system.log
```

Found :

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/cassandra/data/system/compactions_in_progress-55080ab05d9c388690a4acb25fe1f77b/system-compactions_in_progress-tmp-ka-72-Data.db (No space left on device)
```

Issue an :

```
df -h
```

And check the space left on the partition where cassandra's data and commitlogs are located. Probably you`re using defaults (/var/lib) and root partition might be full (usually is defaulted at 50 Gb on OS installation and includes /var)

Hope it helps.